# Manipulating data on parent with $event or via $parent in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm fairly new to Vue.js and I ended up manipulating an array on a parent component using $parent. I'm just wondering if there is some danger in doing it like this:

```
setTitle(title) {
        this.$parent.items[this.index].name = title;
        this.editTitle = false;
}
```

Instead of emitting an event with $emit, and then listening for that on the parent?

Will this burn me in any way in the future?

I' wondering because I've never seen it showed like the first solution in any of the tutorials I've come across.

Comment: It's not the end of the world, but the parent/child components are now tightly coupled. If the parent for w/e reason does not have an `items` array, your app will break. Also, let's say you want to reuse the child component in another parent component, but you want to handle `setTitle` differently. With events, this is trivial, you just handle the event.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some danger in manipulating a parent through a child, similar to manipulating a child through a parent. The main issue tends to come in separation of responsibility and coupling, if you reuse the code you need to remove or modify any code that manipulates another object in the system.

By emitting an event and letting the parent handle the updated information you can reuse the object in multiple places without modification as any parent that doesn't need to update their items can just ignore the event.

It also makes it harder to maintain the code as someone might see the array get updated but not see the code in the parent object that updates it. In your example it would not be hard to find but if your program became more complex it could take time to find and update or debug.